# React "Commiting Host Effects" takes around ~13 Seconds in profiler. How to break Down these commits in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Profiler Screenshot]

Context: A table with around 1000 rows is unmounted and few other components are mounted in its place. (Conditional Rendering)

How can I break down these 13 Commits to see which one took the most time ?